# Why does transfer of BitMap reverse order in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

When the button is clicked, images should be transferred from richedit1 to richedit2 and displayed in order, and they are displayed in reverse. How to fix it? Below is the code.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if OpenPictureDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(OpenPictureDialog1.FileName);
    InsertBitmapToRE(RichEdit1.Handle, Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Handle);
  end;
end;

Function MAP_LOGHIM_TO_PIX(Const Val: Integer; Const Log: Integer): Integer;
Const
  HIMETRIC_PER_INCH=2540;
Begin
  Result:=MulDiv(Val, Log, HIMETRIC_PER_INCH);
End;

Function MAP_LOGHIMPT_TO_PT(Const Val: TPoint; Const Handle: HWND = 0): TPoint;
Var
  DC: HDC;
Begin
  DC:=GetDC(Handle);
  Result.X:=MAP_LOGHIM_TO_PIX(Val.X, GetDeviceCaps(DC, LOGPIXELSX));
  Result.Y:=MAP_LOGHIM_TO_PIX(Val.Y, GetDeviceCaps(DC, LOGPIXELSY));
  ReleaseDC(Handle, DC);
End;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
  IREO: IRichEditOle;
  OleClientSite: IOleClientSite;
  ReObject: TReObject;
  I: Integer;
  ViewObject2: IViewObject2;
  Rc: TRect;
  Path:String;
  bmp:TBitmap;
  Pt: TPoint;
begin
  Path:='C:\temp\richedit\';
  SendMessage(RichEdit1.Handle, EM_GETOLEINTERFACE, 0, Longint(@IREO));
  IREO.GetClientSite(OleClientSite);
  For I:=IREO.GetObjectCount-1 Downto 0 Do
  Begin
    ZeroMemory(@ReObject, SizeOf(ReObject));
    ReObject.cbStruct:=SizeOf(ReObject);
    If Succeeded(IREO.GetObject(I, ReObject, $00000001)) Then
    If Succeeded(ReObject.poleobj.QueryInterface(IViewObject2, ViewObject2)) Then
    Begin
      ViewObject2.GetExtent(DVASPECT_CONTENT, -1, Nil, Pt);
      Pt:=MAP_LOGHIMPT_TO_PT(Pt, RichEdit1.Handle);
      bmp:=TBitmap.Create;
      Bmp.Height := Pt.Y;
      Bmp.Width := Pt.X;
      SetRect(Rc, 0, 0, Bmp.Width, Bmp.Height);
      OleDraw(ReObject.poleobj, DVASPECT_CONTENT, bmp.Canvas.Handle, Rc);
      bmp.SaveToFile(Path+'Img'+IntToStr(I+1)+'.bmp');
      InsertBitmapToRE(RichEdit2.Handle, bmp.Handle);
    End
    Else
      ShowMessage('Error: Can''t get IViewObject2');
  End;
end;
```

screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: `For I:=IREO.GetObjectCount-1 Downto 0 Do` and using `I` in `GetObject()` will retrieve the objects in reserve order.

Comment: @Brian thank you for your input! Please reply as an "Answer" since this seems to solve it.

Comment: @Tigerjz32, I know it is an offtopic, but if you were able to change title of question, be too kind to improve also formatting of the code in question. Start from that string: *bmp.SaveToFile(*. I coul do this myself but SO's system told me there is a lot of code, so I can't done editing. Thank you.

Comment: @Lex34, unfortunately I am not too familiar with Delphi to make edits to the code syntax. I was hoping another community member can help with that if they know it better. I changed the title because I understand the problem and wanted to make it accessible for future users.

Comment: On a side note, you should be using the built-in image upload here in SO. Readers don't like when people use third-party websites for things like that, especially with a URL such as the one you provided. For all we know, we might get a virus by clicking on it.

Answer (score 4):

Using `downto 0` in a for loop is efficient but counts in reverse so is not always desirable. This is such a case since you are using the loop variable as an index and want a specific order of processing.

`For I:= 0 to IREO.GetObjectCount-1 Do`

Comment: It works, and if I need to display text together with pictures when I click on the button? The screenshot shows that the image was transferred, but the text is not there. https://vfl.ru/fotos/9b733a3223438746.html 

How can I transfer text with pictures?

Comment: @Lex34: that is a different question, so you should ask that as a new one.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: I need to ask a new question in order to get an answer to it?

Comment: What has his got to do with efficiency?

Comment: @Lex34: if you want to know how to display text together with pictures, you should ask a new question, indeed. The current question was about the image being reversed.

Comment: @David: I *assume* Brian means that, if possible (i.e. if it doesn't change the outcome), the optimizer will make loops run down to 0. Checking against 0 is often easier (single opcode) than checking against a stored loop limit. But that only works if the *optimizer* changes the loop, not if you do this in code.